# How to pass "System.Object" type to the Controller through a FromQuery parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web, amazon-dynamodb

I have this method in my controller that needs to receive a List of filtering expressions, so I can filter a DynamoDB table but the Value to filter can be string, numeric, boolean, etc...
so I used a "System.Object" typed property. But it seems the controller can't bind a FromQuery Parameter to a Type "System.Object" object.

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get(
            [FromRoute]string name,
            [FromQuery]FilterExpression[] filters
            )
        {
            return Ok(m_attributeService.GetByAttributeName(name, filters));
        }
```

The FilterExpression class

```cs
    public class FilterExpression
    {
        public FilterExpression(){}
        public FilterExpression(
            string field, 
            string comparisonOperator, 
            dynamic values
            )
        {
            Field = field;
            ComparisonOperator = comparisonOperator;
            Values = values;
        }

        public string Field { get;set; }
        public string ComparisonOperator { get;set; }
        public object Values { get;set; }
    }
```

But every time I do any request the Values Property is always **null**.
I want to know a workaround solution to receive different data types on my method.

Comment: That's because in a query everything is a string, until it gets casted by the framework based on the types you specify. How can the framework automatically differentiate between types in a string of `?values=1&values=true&values=foo`? Just because it says 1 or true doesn't mean you don't want those as a string.  You need to specify custom logic somewhere that says if it's a number, cast it, if it's a boolean cast it etc. Whether that's by comparing strings or using `int.TryParse`/`bool.TryParse` is up to you.

Comment: If it's only needed for one endpoint, I'd just accept Values as a list/array of strings and coerce it with a custom function. If it's for many, some custom middleware might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to whatever you like. However, the modelbinder must inspect the type to determine what properties it can bind to and then bind the data from the request accordingly. `Object` has no properties, and thus, the modelbinder will bind nothing to it.  I'd imagine you're attempting to polymorphically bind, but that's not how model-binding works. Even though actions are technically methods, they do not function like a regular method would because they are dynamically invoked. When you as a developer are upcasting some object by passing into a method, you still have the full object, and can therefore always downcast it back to its type later. In the request pipeline, the modelbinder just has a collection string key-value pairs that it's trying to interpret as some type. It must know what type to create from the action param, so if you use a base type, all you get is the base type. All extraneous data will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I think custom data binder can help you. See more in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trick used by *Json Serializers* as a solution.

**Controller, Action & Model**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public bool Get([FromQuery] Filter filter)
    {
        filter = Request.Query.ExtractFilter();
        return true;
    }
}

public class Filter
{
    public object Equal { get; set; }
}
```

**The Extension Method**

```
public static class QueryCollectionExtensions
{
    public static Filter ExtractFilter(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> queryCollection)
    {
        Filter result = new();

        if (!queryCollection.TryGetByKey("filter", out StringValues filter))
        {
            return result;
        }

        if (!filter.Any())
        {
            return result;
        }

        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filter>(filter);

        return result;
    }

    public static bool TryGetByKey(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> queryCollection,
        string key, out StringValues values)
    {
        values = string.Empty;

        KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> keyValuePair = queryCollection
            .FirstOrDefault((KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> x) => x.Key == key);

        if (keyValuePair.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        values = keyValuePair.Value;

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Request URLs**

```
https://localhost:7134/api/test?filter={"Equal":50}
https://localhost:7134/api/test?filter={"Equal":"abc"}
```