# ASP.Net Core 6 HttpGet API ==> How to bind [FromQuery] parameter to C# object data type

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, model-binding, http-get

I'm trying to pass a value to an endpoint created with ASP.Net Core 6 API with the following details:

**Controller, Action & Model**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/test")]
public class TestController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public bool Get([FromQuery] Filter filter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Filter
{
    public object Equal { get; set; }
}
```

**Request URL**

```
https://localhost:7134/api/test?Equal=50
```

As you can see the `Equal` property is of type `object`.

**Note**
Here is a simplified version of the situation I'm facing, and the `Filter` model is not changeable by me.

**The Question**
How can I bind `50` to the `Equal` property of the `filter` object without writing a custom model binder?

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481252/how-to-pass-system-object-type-to-the-controller-through-a-fromquery-parameter), you can see `Object` has no properties, the modelbinder will bind nothing to it.

Comment: Maybe you're right.

Comment: @Qing Guo thanks for the question link. I did not find it in my search :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result, I was able to accomplish the goal by using the trick that *Json Serializers* have.

**Controller, Action & Model**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public bool Get([FromQuery] Filter filter)
    {
        filter = Request.Query.ExtractFilter();
        return true;
    }
}

public class Filter
{
    public object Equal { get; set; }
}
```

**The Extension Method**

```
public static class QueryCollectionExtensions
{
    public static Filter ExtractFilter(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> queryCollection)
    {
        Filter result = new();

        if (!queryCollection.TryGetByKey("filter", out StringValues filter))
        {
            return result;
        }

        if (!filter.Any())
        {
            return result;
        }

        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filter>(filter);

        return result;
    }

    public static bool TryGetByKey(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> queryCollection,
        string key, out StringValues values)
    {
        values = string.Empty;

        KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> keyValuePair = queryCollection
            .FirstOrDefault((KeyValuePair<string, StringValues> x) => x.Key == key);

        if (keyValuePair.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        values = keyValuePair.Value;

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Request URLs**

```
https://localhost:7134/api/test?filter={"Equal":50}
https://localhost:7134/api/test?filter={"Equal":"abc"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you want is :

```
https://localhost:7134/api/test?Filter.Equal=50
```

Comment: Thank you James, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing it as another parameter?

e.g. :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public bool Get([FromQuery] int Equal, [FromQuery] Filter filter)
    {
        if (null == filter)
        {
            filter = new Filter();
        }

        filter.Equal = Equal;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Dang-gun. But as I mentioned in the question, this is a simplified version of the situation I'm facing. I meant that the filter model contains some other properties and nested models as well.

Comment: Also there are two problems with this method. In the first place, the dynamic type should remain. The second problem is that an additional mapping is required.

Comment: @Milad Rashidi As far as I know "system.object" is not bound.
So unless you make a "custom model binder",
It must be dealt with separately.